# Final period in IIS URL causes 404

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

URIs with a trailing period seems to be problematic for IIS. I have configured IIS to include a wide range of characters for my ASP.NET MVC 5 app, including periods and other characters (&, %, +, - etc.). Only in cases of period as the last character does IIS give a 404 without ever hitting the controller.

I've added some commonly suggested points of configuration to allow the unusual characters. I have a large set of data with little control over the URIs permissible. The data is all served by the controller and does not map to a file system.

```
<location path="data">
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"/>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
    </security>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="DataHandler" path="*" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What it should show if there is a period at the end of url? Did you try doing url encoding of period ?

Comment: The URI reaches data by the same name. Encoding the period at the end does not make a difference in the result.